# The component dot't render when it must be rendered

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/patr4519/githubUserInfo.git

The essence of the application:
In input entering logins of github users separated by commas, the app shows the result consisting of photo, user name and data reg. After entering the user (users) into the input and pressing the Enter button, an array with users in the form of objects gets into the users state, which are then used to display cards.

The problem is that the Main component is rendered only after the Enter button is pressed and some other action is performed, for example, pressing the Clear button or additional input in the input field, despite the fact that the users state is updated after pressing the Enter button. And in theory, there should be a rerender, which does not happen when it is necessary.

What could be the problem? I attach a link to the repository.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <Nav />
      <Header />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}

function Main() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('');

  const onChangeSearchValue = (event) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }

  const addUsers = () => {
    let arrOfJson = []
    for (let user of searchValue.split(', ')) {
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
        .then(us => us.json())
        .then((json) => arrOfJson.push(json))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
    setUsers(arrOfJson);
  }

  const clearInput = () => {
    setSearchValue('')
  }

  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <InputForm addUsers={addUsers} onChangeSearchValue={onChangeSearchValue} clearInput={clearInput} />
      <Users users={users} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` is asynchronous so when you have `setUsers` after a loop inside `addUsers`, it stores an empty array actually because data hasn't been populated yet:

```
  const addUsers = () => {
    let arrOfJson = []
    for (let user of searchValue.split(', ')) {
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
        .then(us => us.json())
        .then((json) => arrOfJson.push(json))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
    setUsers(arrOfJson); // sets an empty array
  }
```

You can fix with something like this:

```
  const addUsers = async () => {
    for (let user of searchValue.split(", ")) {
      let resultJson = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`);
      let result = await resultJson.json();
      setUsers((ps) => [...ps, result]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: arrOfJson are not empty. It's filled after FOR cycle.

Comment: @Alex Each fetch is asynchronous right? So first the `setUsers` is run.

Comment: Yes, but after calling addUsers function, user state in App stores object of github users

Comment: Oh, thanks man! I've thought long and hard about it.
Thank you very much

Comment: @Alex Nice if it solves the issue you can mark the answer as accepted